# scan strings for 100x100 numbers in c programming

Tags: c, scanf

I have been searching all google or stackoverflow, but could not found it. :(

I have 100 strings, each string is a number with length = 100, the strings are seperated by a break_line.
Example of input:

```
010011001100..... (100 numbers)
...(98 strings)
0011010101010.... (100 numbers)
```

the ouput should be an array A[100][100] for each single number from the strings.

My codes do not work, could you please help to correct it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[100][100];
int b[100][100];
int i,j;


int main(void)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j ++){
            scanf ("%s", a[i][j]);
            b[i][j] = a[i][j] - '0';
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Thank you so much. !

Comment: "*I have been searching all google ...*" really? whow! ;-)

Comment: `scanf("%1d", &b[i][j]);`

Comment: Compile with all warnings on, and fix the code until no more warnings are issued.

Comment: scanf ("%s", a[i][j]); is this intentional ?

Comment: To expect the user to input (without any errors) 100 lines of 100 characters each is beyond reasonable expectation.   Suggest editing a file that will contain the 100 lines of 100 characters each.   Then input each line via fgets() or getline().  Regarding scanf() 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) if using scanf() which I would strongly warn against, always put a max length modifier on the %s.  However, with array sizes of 100, then only 99 characters can be entered per line because scanf() appends a NUL char.

Comment: if the source lines are 100 characters long, then: using scanf() each buffer must be 101 characters long to allow for the (scanf() supplied NUL string terminator char.   using fgets() then each buffer must be 103 characters long (102 on non windows/DOS OSs) to allow for the trailing "\n" and NUL terminator character.  Or read into separate buffer and copy the first 100 characters to the array.   The scanf() will fail on the second line of input because %s stops at any white space (newline) and nothing has been done to consume that newline.

Comment: this line: `scanf ("%s", a[i][j]);` is trying to input to a single char.  all scanf input parameters must be pointers.  suggest: `scanf (" %99s", a[i]);`  Notice the leading space to consume white space and an array name, in C, degrades to a pointer to that array, so 'a[i]' will be a pointer to the ith row in that 2d array

Comment: "my codes don't work"  please clarify that statement.  Note when compiling, always enable all the warnings and fix those warnings.  (for gcc at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  so, 1) the code fails to cleanly compile, fix that before doing anything else

Comment: there seems to be a logic problem. the outer 'for' loop is executing the inner 'for' loop 100 times. The inner 'for' loop is reading a string 100 times into successive rows in the 2D array. (a total of 100 * (100 *100byte strings) ). (the inner 'for' loop will, by itself, read 100 strings of 100 bytes each. Then modifies the jth character in the current row from ascii to int (the -'0' operation) then prints that one int. The scanf() reading a unlimited %s from 100 byte lines will overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got [the answer for my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536667/scan-strings-for-100x100-numbers-in-c-programming#comment52931306_32536667) from Mr./Ms. [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy).

It is

```
scanf("%1d", &b[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[100][100]; /* No space for the NUL-terminator */
int b[100][100];
int i,j;


int main(void)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j ++){
            scanf ("%s", a[i][j]); /* %s expects a char*, not a char */
            b[i][j] = a[i][j] - '0';
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It should be

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[100][101]; /* Note the 101 instead of 100 */
int b[100][100];
int i,j;


int main(void)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
        scanf ("%s", a[i]); /* Scan a string */
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j++){
            b[i][j] = a[i][j] - '0';
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[100][100]; /* No need for space for the NUL-terminator as %s isn't used */
int b[100][100];
int i,j;


int main(void)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j ++){
            scanf (" %c", &a[i][j]); /* Scan one character, space before %c ignores whitespace characters like '\n' */
            b[i][j] = a[i][j] - '0';
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, the code has a lot more than just two problems.  Your third example does manage to fix those problems